# Adding a `lastModified` record to a Core Data managed object

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

An object needs to be submitted to the server, and I want to indicate to the user that the object needs to be submitted by displaying the `lastModified` date/time, and `lastSubmitted` date/time.

(Yes, the record must be manually submitted.)

I'm currently listening for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`, checking if the object's entity is `RetailLocation`, and if so, setting its `lastModified` date/time (of course, only if `lastModified` is not the only property being modified). Since this seems to highly confuse the undo manager, I use `performSelector:SOMESEL withObject:retailLocation afterDelay:0.0` to set the `lastModified` property.

Sadly, this is almost even worse: this results in two actions being added to the undo stack!

Can someone recommend a nice way to implement a `lastModified` attribute in a Core Data-managed record? Alternatively, what am I missing?

Comment: Check out Martin R's answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098544/set-a-lastmodificationdate-attribute-after-nsmanagedobjectsdidchangenotification. That solution worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the modification date to be undoable, you can call `disableUndoRegistration` on your NSUndoManager before making changes, and `enableUndoRegistration` when you're done.

If you need one, you can get a pointer to the NSUndoManager by calling `undoManager` on your NSManagedObjectContext, but if you're working in iOS you should have one already.

Also, note Apple recommends using the `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` notification for this, since changes might not necessarily be saved.

Comment: I'm using `NSPersistentDocument`'s undo manager (which is the same as `NSManagedObjectContext`'s), on OS X. Disabling undo registration does not seem to help, but that's not the ideal solution anyway; if the user performs undo, both modification time and the action should undo within the same undo operation. Ideally this would be done via undo groups, but that's not an option here, considering Core Data is the one that adds operations to undo stack, based on changes triggered by Cocoa Bindings, which are triggered based on user input deep in main runloop... :/

Comment: I'd go for the `...WillSaveNotification` solution, but the user needs to immediately see that a submission of updated data to the server is necessary. This mildly complex set of requirements is why I ran to SO; I don't see a clean way to do this except by either: 1) not integrating modification tracking as a Core Data attribute, or 2) doing tracking by overriding every single setter of existing Core Data attributes (thus ensuring that tracking is done within the same undo group). I don't like either of the solutions.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you might need to override every setter and make a new custom undo group.

Comment: Just curious, what did you end up doing?

Comment: I'm still sticking with the flawed solution where I have two undo actions on the stack. Never got around to adding custom setters into the class for the entity, but that's the planned route… It's nasty, but it should work.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`? From the [NSManagedObjectContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification) docs it looks like `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` doesn't pass a userInfo dictionary while `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` does.

Comment: FYI, just verified...I'm not seeing a userInfo dictionary for `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`, but I do see one for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` in iOS 7.